# Prestashop 1.6 - How to add a dynamic class to the body element

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In a Prestashop 1.6 site I need add a dynamic class to the body element (just in frontend).

The class should be 'group-[group-name-id]' where group-name-id is the group name id of the visitor.

Default Groups in Presashop are:

'1'--'Visitor'

'2'--'Guest'

'3'--'Costumer'

Is there a way to do this?

I found this, but it seems outdated, since it is for PS 1.4: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/179593-adding-category-class-id-to-product-page-body/

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I almost get it thanks to @TheDrot answer (just below).

The only problem is this: [0]. I get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/temporal-4/www/override/classes/controller/FrontController.php on line 36".

If I remove '[0]' it works but then in the class I get "group-array". I need to print all the values of the array like class="group-1 group-2 group-3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override FrontControllerCore class so create a file FrontController.php in folder 'override/classes/controller/' and put in this code

```php
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {
    public function init() 
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('group_id', $this->context->customer->getGroups()[0]; // user can exist in multiple groups, so for this example im just grabbing first group id
    }
}
```

Then open header.tpl file in 'themes/your_theme/' and add code to body class

```
group-{$group_id}
```

If in body class you only see group-, be sure to delete class_index.php from cache folder and reload page.

Comment: In the file 'FrontController.php' I already have this code: http://pastebin.com/raw/bm9yY3TT Can you tell me where  do I insert your code in the array? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter where in the array you put it. All you have to do is add 'group_id' => $this->context->customer->getGroups()[0] into the array.

Comment: I just did it. I copied and pasted the code here: http://pastebin.com/raw/ZuCUdpyQ You can see it in the last position of the array. But now I get empy page with a 500 ERROR in my site.

Comment: That is weird. I tried it on my server and it works just fine. Did you delete class_index.php from cache?

Comment: Yes, I just did it, but I stil see a HTTP ERROR 500. :(  Did you see my file http://pastebin.com/raw/ZuCUdpyQ  ? Maybe my array is not the same as yours.

Comment: I copy-pasted your array and it worked fine. Is this on live site or dev? Can you turn on php errors or check php error logs to see whats going on?

Comment: The problem is this: [0]. The error says: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/temporal-4/www/override/classes/controller/FrontController.php on line 36". If I remove '[0]' it works but the in the class I get "group-array". I need to print  all the values of the array like class="group-1 group-2 group-3".

Comment: Got it. I just used a foreach() sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For PS1.7 no need to override anything, perhaps it works for PS1.6

Add $groupid = "group-1" or "group-2", ect. to smarty params by using assign() function in your controller and in your template add on top

```
{$page["body_classes"][$groupid] = 'true'}
```

Let us know about this tricks